# Powershell script - check exit code

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Hi I have the following script:

```
foreach ($server in $ProductList.$SelectedServer){

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential domain\user -ScriptBlock {

Import-Module WebAdministration
echo "restarting AppPool $args[0] ... on $args[1]"
Restart-WebAppPool -Name $args[0] -ErrorAction stop
echo "Restarted WebApp $args[0] on $args[1]"}
} -ArgumentList $SelectedAppPool, $Server
```

I would like to check if the Restart-WebAppPool command executes successfully. If it does I echo 'it worked' else echo 'It did not work'.

The goal is to provide a simple plain english message rather than the typical unhandled exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use a try-catch block like this:

```
Try  {
      Restart-WebAppPool -Name $args[0] -ErrorAction stop
      echo "it worked"
     } 
Catch{
      echo "it didn't work"
     }
```